# Can not connect database with Yii Framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii1.x

I've trying to run an application in a remote server and then connect this web application via my computer's browser. I got an error when connecting to database.

The error message is : `CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

I saw many solutions for solve it and tried it, but nothing helps.

Current os is Ubuntu 18.04, nginx version is `nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)`, php version is `5.6.40`, mysql version is `5.7.24` and yii `1.1.19` version used. All of this stack installed on remote server.

What I've tried so far;
I've checked the user has exist.
`SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;`

```
    | user              | host          |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | root              | 127.0.0.1     |
    | root              | localhost     |
    +-------------------+---------------+
```

and it's OK.

I've checked mysql running port.

```
 mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
 +---------------+-------+
 | Variable_name | Value |
 +---------------+-------+
 | port          | 3306  |
 +---------------+-------+
```

I've checked grant privileges;

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS  For root@localhost;
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                            
|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                     
| GRANT SELECT ON `root`.* TO 'root'@'localhost'            
|GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xxxx`.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
| GRANT SELECT ON `xxxx`.* TO 'root'@'localhost'   
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+


mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@127.0.0.1                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION  
|
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xxxx`.* TO 
'root'@'127.0.0.1' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In php side, there are some files seperated by environment. For ex: development.php, test.php.

I've trigger to run development.php and it includes a connection string:

```
 db' => array(
 'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=xxxx',
         'enableParamLogging' => $profiling,
         'enableProfiling' => $profiling,
         'schemaCachingDuration' => 0,
     ),
```

username and password loaded by another php file like this:

```
 'db' => array(
         'class' => 'DbConnection',
         'emulatePrepare' => true,
         'username' => 'root',
         'password' => 'xxxx',
         'charset' => 'utf8',
         'schemaCachingDuration' => 7200,

     ),
```

Everthing seems normal. I can also connect mysql terminal for that user and password like this:
`mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1`

But when I type the url in the browser, it gives: 
`CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` 
error and I couldn't find a way to solve it.

Comment: This error means one of your connection parameters is wrong. Username, Password or user privilege. Make sure the user has enough privileges for the server which you call it using URL. Also, make sure all configuration of the database, anywhere is correct.

Comment: @HamedGhasempour, the error is very clear. But , I couldn't see any error. Also check username and password. Grant priviliges seems OK as you saw. The user I request via browser is important? Because, web application and database lives in remote server and all configuration is located in php files. If yes, what type of priviliges are we talking about? Can you be more spesific?

Comment: You know, I can clearly ask if your PHP file is located where the DB is? or not? Because if the locations of these are different, So the user of the database should have PHP server address as HOST.

Comment: @HamedGhasempour, I've specified it. Php and database and other stuff located in remote server. I just make request another client machine to this web server. Php can access database, I've already tried it but with yii , there is problem specified it in the question.

Comment: Can you connect to the DB using Mysqli or PDO (not Yii)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe trying localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

```
return array(
    'class'              => 'CDbConnection',
    'connectionString'   => "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxx;port=3306",
    'emulatePrepare'     => true,
    'username'           => 'root',
    'password'           => 'xxxx',
    'charset'            => 'utf8',
    'enableProfiling'    => true,
    'enableParamLogging' => true
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

There is a configuration which I couldn't figure it out. In the application, password has defined more than once. And some people merge it using `ArrayHelper::merge`.

So, I thougth that password store in the an array called `array1`. But already defined in the `array2`

When using `ArrayHelper::merge($array1, $array2);`, `array2` has override the `array1`. 
I couldn't figure it out for a long time. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

add the following lines and check XAMMP MySql server started or not(some times xammp connected different database).

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'xxx',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But I didn't see difference from my config. These properties already exist in my config. The only difference is `yii\db\Connection`, but in my config `DbConnection` class does this job already. It extends `CDbConnection` class which is responsible for creating database connection. Plus, I've using nginx not XAMPP and I am sure mysql server runs.

Comment: yii\db\Connection is from Yii2. Yii1 uses another class CDbConnection